# export a content type form into a module in drupal6

Tags: drupal, forms, module, export, cck

is there a way to export the form structure of content type and put it in a module as same as we can do in views? (and all the cck ofcourse)
$form['item']=.....

Comment: you should accept some answers ("mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer") if you want people to continue helping you.

Answer (score 1):

See the [Features](http://drupal.org/project/features) module. When you create a feature, you can include node types, CCK, views, ImageCache presets and even module dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like what you are looking for here in more detail:

http://www.tinpixel.com/node/53

I also use the following code on my sites, the function is a fork from the method used by the install_profile api module and I use this on my sites rather than loading the full module:

http://drupal.org/project/install_profile_api

```
function MYMODULE_install_content_copy_import_from_file($file) {
  // The import will be populate into the $content variable.
  $content = array();

  ob_start();
  include $file;
  ob_end_clean();

  $form_state['values']['type_name'] = '';
  $form_state['values']['macro'] = '$content = '. var_export($content, 1) .';';
  $form_state['values']['op'] = t('Import');

  drupal_execute('content_copy_import_form', $form_state);
}
```